# How to extract current version of Windows through KQL in Azure?

Tags: azure, kql

We are planning to upgrade all our 2012-R2 Servers to 2019 Server, and to do this we need to get an overview of all our 2012 server in Azure.

We are now using this KQL query to get the information of what version is installed, but we noticed that this is only including the windows version FIRST installed, and not the current installed windows version. Is there any ways to get the current windows version out of an Azure KQL script?

```
Resources 
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
| project resourceGroup, version = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.sku, minorversion=properties.storageProfile.imageReference.exactVersion
| join ResourceContainers on resourceGroup
| project resourceGroup, tags.Description, version, minorversion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with below script

```
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
| project resourceGroup, name, initial_OSVersion = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.sku, current_OS = properties.extended.instanceView.osName, current_OSVersion = properties.extended.instanceView.osVersion
| join ResourceContainers on resourceGroup
| project customer_Name = tags.Description, ComputerName = name, current_OS,initial_OSVersion,  current_OSVersion, resourceGroup
| order by tostring(current_OS) asc
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).